# SELinux повесил систему из-за диска D, почему?

Tags: linux, kali-linux, selinux

Заранее озвучу некоторые особенности своей системы:

```
OS: Kali Linux amd64 2021.4
Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-2 kali2-amd64

Диски:
/dev/sda1 (ext4, rootfs, /)
/dev/sda2 (ntfs, диск D:, /home/rdice779/disk_d)

Модули ядра dkms:
virtualbox_dkms модули
rtl8192eu WiFi driver

FSTAB:
/dev/sda1 /                     ext4  rw,user_xattr
/dev/sda2 /home/rdice779/disk_d ntfs  rw,nosuid,nodev,remove_hiberfile,permissions,user_xattr
tmpfs     /tmp                  tmpfs rw,nodev,user_xattr
```

Короче, я попытался установить SELinux. Установил, задал политику **targeted**, **permissive**, создал */.autorelabel*, исполнил `selinux_enabled`. Но после перезагрузки оказалось, что SELinux повесил систему. Первый раз система попыталась запуститься, но выдала кучу мной никогда ранее не виданных ошибок (я с таким впервые столкнулся. Прочитать не успел, система тут же перезагрузилась, но уже в *emergency mode*). `/var/log/audit.log` **отсутствовал!!**. Смотрю `journalctl -xe` - а там сообщение от *watchdog*, которое ничего внятного не говорит. Смотрю `dmesg -l err`, и вижу, что SELinux не даёт смонтировать диск D: (что странно, при, мало того, что **targeted**, так ещё и **permissive** политике) *(неужели SELinux даже в permissive/targeted как то запрещает монтирование, по крайней мере, сторонних дисков)*. Как решить эту проблему? Сразу скажу: мне нужна политика *enabled*, но **targeted(!!)**, плюс добавлю свои политики. Я специально хочу *targeted*, чтобы не подвесить насмерть систему.

Comment: хоть я и снес selinux (через LiveUSB), но проблема по прежнему актуальна. Я хочу нормально поставить SELinux в систему